# Using basemap fillcontinents with color causes error

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

**Packages versions:**

```
basemap : 1.2.2
matplotlib : 3.5.1
GEOS : 3.9.1
```

With this code I get the following map, in which fillcontinents doesn't cover the Antarctic region :

```py
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='grey')
plt.show()
```

[image: my_map]

Answer (score 1):

Currently (22 April 2022), `basemap` works well only with GEOS < 3.9 (see [basemap #522](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/522#issuecomment-1021245967)). This problem with Antarctica is known to appear with GEOS >= 3.9. Until the bug is solved, a GEOS downgrade should fix your problem with the Antarctica coastline.

**EDIT (2022-10-26):** Since `basemap` version 1.3.5, the bug related to the drawing of Antarctica is solved. The precompiled wheels in PyPI are still linked to GEOS 3.5.1, but a user installing from the source distribution will be able to link `basemap` to GEOS >= 3.9 and now Antarctica would also be drawn correctly for the case of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @molinav problem solved by downgrading GEOS from 3.9 to 3.8.1 by

```
pip install geos==3.8.1
```

and now the map looks like that :
[image: figure_after]

Comment: You can consider accepting the answer if it helped. ;-)