# Basemap shows only half of Antarctica

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

Hi I have downloaded the Basemap Wheel from the site:
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

i used the version: basemap-1.2.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

my Python version is: [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Unfortunately Basemap now only shows me half of Antarctica, what should I do?
[image]

Ok, this is not due to the wheel from the website but must be due to something else. I have also unistralised and reloaded everything several times, but that doesn't change anything.

Additional Informations:

Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Name: numpy
Version: 1.22.3

Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.5.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using basemap fillcontinents with color causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972326/using-basemap-fillcontinents-with-color-causes-error)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem in `basemap` when used in combination with GEOS >= 3.9, see e.g. this other question:

[Using basemap fillcontinents with color causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972326/using-basemap-fillcontinents-with-color-causes-error/71972997#71972997)

Until this is patched in `basemap`, your only way to solve it is to use an older version of GEOS. If you install `basemap` for Windows using the official wheels for `basemap` 1.3.x available in PyPI, you should have no problem because they are linked against GEOS 3.5.1:

```
python -m pip install basemap
```

**EDIT (2022-10-26):** Since `basemap` version 1.3.5, the bug related to the drawing of Antarctica is solved. The precompiled wheels in PyPI are still linked to GEOS 3.5.1, but a user installing from the source distribution will be able to link `basemap` to GEOS >= 3.9 and now Antarctica would also be drawn correctly for the case of the OP.